# git hook post receive not finding env: node: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, bash, git

I have an idea of what is the problem, but I don't know how to fix. My issue is when I run the script /post-recieve. I get the error `env: node: No such file or directory`. I think it may be because its a non interactive shell. And that I should change the $PATH, but I dont understand enough to know what I need to do. When I source the file, npm works with out any issues. It only occurs when I call the script else where remotely.

So I'm using homebrew nodev8 and postgres.
I also have nvm managing node

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

. $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh

echo 'post-receive: Triggered.'

cd /Users/david/Development/abba/live/404

echo 'post-receive: git check out...'

git --git-dir=/Users/david/Development/abba/404.git --work-tree=/Users/david/Development/abba/live/404 checkout master -f

/Users/david/.nvm/v8.15.0/bin/npm install && echo 'post-receive: -> done.'
```

which node `/Users/david/.nvm/v8.15.0/bin/node`

$PATH `/Users/david/.nvm/v8.15.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin`

My bash_profile

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:"

export NVM_DIR="/Users/david/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Comment: I'm currently facing the exact same problem. Did you get it solved?

Comment: @acb1980 no, I don't think so.. its been a while, since i last looked at it. I'll take a stab at it again soon though. Any progress on your end?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. It seems not to be possible to use node on a systems that generates this error. I've changed my workflow now so that I call node on another machine in the build process. Not the perfect solution, but it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this same issue when trying to have a git post-receive hook trigger a build step. In my case, I solved the issue by symlinking the node binary into the /usr/bin/folder

```
ln -s `which node` /usr/bin/node
```

I found a github issue which had a similar error here: https://github.com/animetosho/Nyuu/issues/14.

In that issue they used
`ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`